# Stopping propagation of mouseover in JQuery

Tags: jquery

When I hover over a child element, the parent's event is also called. How do I stop it?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>

$(".parent").on("mouseover", function(){//Shouldnt fire on child})
$(".child").on("mouseover", function(){//Child function})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just catch the event in child and stop its propagation as follows:

```
 $(".child").on("mouseover", function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 //Child function})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stopPropagation` in the child to prevent parent handlers from being notified of the event:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish for the child to experience the  trickle down effect of the parent's mouseover event handler, in the handler for the child's mouseover event, one needs to use  jQuery's  *event.stopPropagation()*. The following example illustrates its usage:

```
$(".parent").on("mouseover", function(){
    alert('parents r family');
});
$(".child").on("mouseover", function( e ){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('kids r children');
});
```

If you use code like `e.stopPropagation()` for the child's mouseover event handler, but overlook  providing that function with an argument e, the code will not execute as one might wish. This occurs with jQuery versions 1.6.4 through 2.1.0, and jQuery edge.

The jQuery documentation specifies that one must provide an argument to hold the event object, as follows (emphasis  mine):

> $( "p" ).click(function( **event** ) {
>     **event**.stopPropagation();
>     // Do something
>   });

Live demo of the [good](http://jsfiddle.net/xd71oecn/7/) and the [weird](http://jsfiddle.net/xd71oecn/5/)

In the "weird" demo, the child's handler function is without any arguments.  So, the first statement in its code uses a bogus event object and unsurprisingly the propagation of the parent's handler is not suppressed at all while the child's event handler fails to execute its remaining code.  By failing to provide the child's function with an argument to hold an event object, the event object in the function's code is non-existent, a fact that the console's log confirms:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined.

The undefined object e is, of course, completely useless as are its methods. This error is sufficient to prevent the rest of the handler for the child from executing.