# How can I fire JQuery event only on child element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

My HTML code is like this

```
<div>
    <p>Parent Element</p>

    <div>
        <p>Child Element</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a JQuery to add a border for every element on mouseover and remove the border on mouseout

```
var border = '';

// On mouseover
$('*').on('mouseover', Hovers);

function Hovers()
{
    border = $(this).css('border');
    $(this).css('border', '1px dashed black');
}

// On mouseout
$('*').on('mouseout', Outs);

function Outs()
{
    $(this).css('border', border);
}
```

It ads and removes borders as expected but whenever I hover the mouse on child element, it adds border to parent as well. I need only the last element I hover to have the border. Any idea to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping propagation of mouseover in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884962/stopping-propagation-of-mouseover-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `stopPropagation()` to stop children to pass the event to the parent in a chain

```
function Hovers(e) {
    border = $(this).css('border');
    $(this).css('border', '1px dashed black');
    e.stopPropagation(); // <--- add this
}
```